# Android admob interstitial add not displaying But Just display The interstitial is already showing

Tags: android, admob

Hello all i need to load interstitial add on my app... But it just displays 
***The interstitial is already showing***. This msg but not display Add.

Actually this project in which i am trying to add interstitial add is a ***Lib  Project***

my AdUnitId is correct.

I have used the same method for loading and displaying add but not display add But only display ***The interstitial is already showing***

What is wrong or if lib project not able to load add?

Comment: Hi, did you find the reason for this log message? I too get it in my app, but so rarely that I cannot find a pattern to reproduce and deal with it. My app is not a lib, just normal app with activities.